# UICollectionView with two custom cells in a section

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on a medical billing application and I have two cells that are for two different types of medical codes. The first is a visit code and the second is a diagnoses code. There can be many diagnoses codes that are added to a particular visit code and I am trying to make a section consist of a single visit code and any number of diagnoses codes (including zero).

```
var icdCodes:[[(icd10:String,icd9:String)]] = [[]]  //A list of diagnoses codes for the bill
var visitCodes:[String] = [] //A list of the visit codes that have been added
```

Currently I have a UICollectionView that I add visit codes to. I am having problems with displaying all of the icd10 cells for each visitCode cell. I can dequeue an "ICD10Cell" but I am not sure if the cell at indexPath is a visitCodeCell or an ICD10Cell.  My dataSource code is below:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return icdCodes[section].count + 1 //add 1 for the initial visitcode cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("visitCodeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CodeTokenCollectionViewCell

    cell.visitCodeLabel.text = visitCodes[indexPath.row]

    cell.deleteCodeButton.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return visitCodes.count
}
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve the kind of functionality I am looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who might have similar needs, I solved my problem by making the visit code a Header cell and using sections based off of my data source. The CollectionView methods are below:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return visitCodes.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return icdCodes[section].count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CONTENT", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ICD10Cell
    let sectionCodes:[(icd10:String, icd9:String)]  = icdCodes[indexPath.section]

    let (icd10String, icd9String) = sectionCodes[indexPath.row]
    cell.ICDLabel.text = icd10String
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "HEADER", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CodeTokenCollectionViewCell

        cell.visitCodeLabel.text = visitCodes[indexPath.section]
        cell.deleteCodeButton.tag = indexPath.section
        return cell
    }
    abort()
}
```

If not using IB the layout needs to be specified and you need to specify the header size in the viewDidLoad() method. The custom cell classes need to be registered in the viewDidLoad() method as well.

```
    let layout = codeCollectionView.collectionViewLayout
    let flow = layout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    flow.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(100, 25)

    codeCollectionView.registerClass(ICD10Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CONTENT")
    codeCollectionView.registerClass(CodeTokenCollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HEADER")
```